# WCF service authentication fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to consume a WCF service in my console app.
My App.Config file looks like this

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_InventItemGroupService" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mydomain.com/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif50/inventitemgroupservice.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_InventItemGroupService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.InventItemGroupService" name="WSHttpBinding_InventItemGroupService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="asd@as" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Console app code to make authentication part.

```
 protected ProgramClass(AifSos.InventItemGroupServiceClient inventItemGroupServiceClient) // Constructor
    {
        MInventItemGroupServiceClient = inventItemGroupServiceClient;
        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        MInventItemGroupServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "un";
        MInventItemGroupServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pw";
        MInventItemGroupServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
    }
```

All seems okay for me, But it always throws an error

```
The caller was not authenticated by the service.
```

Can any one point out what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Go to your Client Project Properties.

a. Go to services tab

Enable this settings and use authentication mode windows

2 change app.config file inside client project with this two sample line

```
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
```

3 change app.config file inside service project

```
<security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
```

4 in client code when you creating service instance and calling for a service use this line to provide login info in service pc.

```
           Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "ETLIT-1";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "etl";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = false;
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "ETLIT-1-PC";
            Console.WriteLine(client.addNumber(23, 2));
```